# Difficulty loading maxent package in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to load up the maxent package in R (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maxent/index.html) but it keeps returning the error:

```
Error: package ‘maxent’ is not installed for 'arch=x86_64'
```

The above is what happens when attempting just to load it from the CRAN repository.  Specifically, when trying to build from the source, it goes:

```
> install.packages('maxent_1.3.3.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type = 'source')
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘maxent_1.3.3.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
    Installing package(s) into     ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘maxent’ ...
** package ‘maxent’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
*** arch - i386
sh: make: command not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘maxent’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/maxent’
* restoring previous     ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/maxent’
```

I've tried building the library from the source, as well as using the Mac OSX binary.  Below is the information regarding my version:

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0     
arch           x86_64                       
os             darwin9.8.0                  
system         x86_64, darwin9.8.0          
status                                      
major          2                            
minor          15.2                         
year           2012                         
month          10                           
day            26                           
svn rev        61015                        
language       R                            
version.string R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
nickname       Trick or Treat
```

I'm doing all this in RStudio (Version 0.97.312).  Has anyone else experienced this problem?  Going into terminal to try to build the library hasn't worked, either.

Comment: I fear that unless you show us the error messages from your attempts at building this, we won't be able to help.

Comment: see change, indicated the different errors when trying different methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message

```
 sh: make: command not found
```

suggests that you don't have the command-line version of the XCode tools installed.  Or maybe you do, but only for `x64` in which case you should tell `R CMD INSTALL` (on the command-line) to not install for both architectures.

Comment: updated to the current version of XCode (had been using a much older version) and installed the command line tools.  Works great, thanks a ton!